# Google Apps Script setFormulasR1C1 gives formula parse error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Google Apps Script to copy formulas from one row to another; however when I call `setFormulasR1C1()` on the new row with `oldRow.getFormulasR1C1()` passed as argument, the formulas do get copied as expected but I get a `Formula parse error` back on the sheet.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
var referenceRowFormulasR1C1 = referenceRow.getFormulasR1C1();
var currentRow = sh.getRange("A"+rowNum+":"+rowNum);
currentRow.setFormulasR1C1(referenceRowFormulasR1C1);
```

Back in the sheets, I get the following error:

[image: screenshot of error]

Formulae of row `82` were copied from row `81`. The formula for `B81` looks like this, and works fine (so does the formula for `B83`):

```
=VLOOKUP(F81,'Transport & Guide Languages & Training'!$A$2:$I$100,5,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realized, the problem was empty values in referenced cells. For example, as soon as I filled cell `F82`, the formula for `B82` fell in place and returned the correct value. Similarly, other formulae started giving correct values as soon as I filled other (empty) referenced cells.